# Terraform AWS Eventbridge Input transformer not applying

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-event-bridge

When trying to use the eventbridge input_transformer i do not receive the transformed object, but instead i get the original object sent directly to SQS.

I currently have the following setup running

```
locals {
  rule-arn = "arn:aws:events:${data.aws_arn.event-rule.region}:${data.aws_arn.event-rule.account}:rule/${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.notification.name}"
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "test-queue" {
  name = "test-queue"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "notification" {
  name           = "test-notification"
  event_bus_name = aws_cloudwatch_event_bus.events.name
  description    = "Listens to all events in the TEST.Notification namespace"
  event_pattern = jsonencode({
    source = [{ "prefix" : "TEST.Notification" }],
  })
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "developer-notification" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.notification.name
  target_id = "SendToSQS"
  arn = aws_sqs_queue.test-queue.arn

  input_transformer {
    input_paths = {
      "detailType" = "$.detail-type",
    }
    input_template = jsonencode(
      {
        "detailType" : "<detailType>"
      }
    )
  }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "test-queue" {
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.test-queue.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow EventBridge to SQS",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.test-queue.arn}",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.notification.arn}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

I am running Terraform version:

```
Terraform v1.2.3
on darwin_arm64
```

I have seen some talk about having to do stuff like

```
"\"<detailType>\""
```

in order to have it work, but i've had no luck with that either, so for brevity/readability i've removed all the weird tricks i've seen people use. My thinking is there's something more basic i am missing here.

Does someone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you add that to the question as well?

Comment: I am not getting an error, so i have no output to help me. I just don't get anything transformed.

Comment: Does your rule even trigger?

Comment: In the sense that I do receive an SQS message, yes, but it's not transformed to the shape I tried to specify.

Comment: So it should say something like `"detailType": "Somevalue"`?

Comment: That is the goal yes.

Comment: I tested your setup here: https://eventbridge-transformer.vercel.app/. It worked.

Comment: I've also used that site to verify the code, but running it via localstack (to keep it free), it silently fails, by not transforming the input.

Comment: Ha, well that's the part that was missing. :) Are you sure all the features are covered in the free version of localstack: https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/feature-coverage/?

Comment: It appears my faith in Localstack was too great... I'll try and put it on AWS and see what happens, and thank you for helping me reach this conclusion :-)